# how to update all my document every day in firestore using cloud function

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

i am build a todo list app in android studio that save the tasks in firestore, i gave each to list dead line ,and i want to check every morning if i reach deadline, i trying to do it with cloud the problem is that i cant find how to get all document in specific path and do some check and rewrite the changes

i download node.js and initialize firebase, and i also tried do it in the console but it do not have this option

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();
// Create and Deploy Your First Cloud Functions
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/write-firebase-functions

 exports.scheduledFunctionCrontab = functions.pubsub.schedule('0 0 6 * *')
//  .timeZone('America/New_York') // Users can choose timezone - default is America/Los_Angeles
  .onRun((context) => {

const overdueSnap = admin.firestore().collection('tasks')
  .where('overdue','==',false)
  .where('due_time', '=<', new Date()).getTime();

await Promise.all(overdueSnap.docs.map((doc) => doc.ref.update({color: true}));

console.log('This will be run every day at 6 AM Eastern!');
return null;
```

});

Answer (score 4):

Your question a bit vague, but it sounds like what you want to do is query for all documents that are overdue and update them. I'll assume that you're storing due dates as [Timestamps](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp) in a `due_time` field and you want to mark an `overdue` field as `true` when a task is overdue. You could do something like:

```
exports.scheduledFunctionCrontab = functions.pubsub
  .schedule('0 0 6 * *')
  .onRun(async (context) => {
     const overdueSnap = await admin.firestore().collection('tasks')
       .where('overdue','==',false)
       .where('due_time' '<=', new Date()).get();

     await Promise.all(overdueSnap.docs.map((doc) => doc.ref.update({overdue: true}));
  });
```

This code does the following:

1. Finds all documents with a `due_time` in the past that don't already have `overdue` marked as `true`.
2. Updates each of those documents in parallel, setting `overdue` to `true`.

Your specifics may be different, but that's a general approach to the type of problem you're describing.

Comment: yes this is exectly what i want,but its give me an error                                                 arsing error: Unexpected token Promise and i update my code

Comment: You need to make sure the function is `async` -- I updated my code above to have a little more context.